# Camera, Ubuntu, modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted

Tags: camera, raspicam, pi-2, ubuntu

I have added a camera to the raspberry but I get the following when trying to load the driver:

```
root@deadlock-desktop:~# modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted
```

I also tried this:

```
root@deadlock-desktop:~# modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1 debug=1 -vv
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:354 kmod_set_log_fn() custom logging function 0x76ef6ac9 registered
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.0-20-rpi2/kernel/drivers/media/platform/bcm2835/bcm2835-v4l2.ko gst_v4l2src_is_broken=1 debug=1
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:868 kmod_module_insert_module() Failed to insert module '/lib/modules/3.18.0-20-rpi2/kernel/drivers/media/platform/bcm2835/bcm2835-v4l2.ko': Operation not permitted
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:321 kmod_unref() context 0x78ab6130 released
```

This is the output from dmesg:

```
root@deadlock-desktop:~# dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.18.0-20-rpi2 (buildd@lgw01-09) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Sun Apr 5 01:56:02 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 3.18.0-20.21-rpi2 3.18.11)
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine: BCM2709
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3a800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 8095cc40, node_mem_map ba093000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1888 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (85c0->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 11 pages/cpu @ba062000 s12928 r8192 d23936 u45056
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s12928 r8192 d23936 u45056 alloc=11*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239776
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=720 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=480 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa01041 bcm2709.serial=0x5ef6b251 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:F6:B2:51 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.disk_led_gpio=47 bcm2709.disk_led_active_low=0 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 elevator=deadline rootwait
*snip*
[ 2125.330226] : bcm2835-v4l2: error -1 while loading driver
```

I also tried upgrading the Raspberry firmware but still no success:

```
root@deadlock-desktop:~# sudo curl -L --output /usr/bin/rpi-update https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10185  100 10185    0     0  49668      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 49926
root@deadlock-desktop:~# rpi-update 
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10185  100 10185    0     0  54160      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 54175
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** We're running for the first time
 *** Backing up files (this will take a few minutes)
 *** Backing up firmware
 *** Backing up modules 3.18.0-20-rpi2
#############################################################
WARNING: This update bumps to rpi-4.0.y linux tree
Be aware there could be compatibility issues with some drivers
Discussion here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=113753
##############################################################
Would you like to proceed? (y/N)
 *** Downloading specific firmware revision (this will take a few minutes)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   168    0   168    0     0    334      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   334
100 46.7M  100 46.7M    0     0  2525k      0  0:00:18  0:00:18 --:--:-- 1679k
 *** Updating firmware
 *** Updating kernel modules
 *** depmod 4.0.6+
 *** depmod 4.0.6-v7+
 *** Updating VideoCore libraries
 *** Using HardFP libraries
 *** Updating SDK
 *** Running ldconfig
 *** Storing current firmware revision
 *** Deleting downloaded files
 *** Syncing changes to disk
 *** If no errors appeared, your firmware was successfully updated to a51e2e072f2c349b40887dbdb8029f9a78c01987
 *** A reboot is needed to activate the new firmware
root@deadlock-desktop:~# reboot
```

Comment: I would comment but don't have the reputation yet. Did you enable the camera through raspi-config? Did you check the blacklist at /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf to make sure it is not there?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you try running `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Yes that is the first line in my question :)

Comment: /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf is empty. Since I am using Ubuntu raspi-config is not available. Dont know if there is a way to install it but if I try to install one of the .deb packages it says package architecture (armel) does not match system (armhf)

Comment: I mis-read it, didn't see you were root. My bad. Might be worth trying just running `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` as the pi user though - computers can be strange about things like that sometimes.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Unfortunately running it as the pi-user gives med the same issue :(

Answer (score 5):

Seem like I found the answer.

It is possible in Ubuntu to add the following lines:

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

to `/boot/firmware/config` to manually enable the camera. After this the modprobe command  works.

Comment: Here is a source for the above information: http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Camera

Comment: This worked for me on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 18.04. The only difference was I added the lines to `/boot/firmware/config.txt`.