# Error loading bc2835-v4l2 driver, Raspberry Pi and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, v4l2

**disclaimer: I am new to OpenCV and Raspberry Pi, although I have a fair amount of experience with linux systems in general**

Here is what I am attempting to accomplish:

- I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi with OpenCV (version 3.0.0) to read a live video stream from a GoPro (or any camera with a live video output).

Here is my setup:

- I have am running Raspbian 3.18.16
- I have an STK1160 video capture card (USB connection)
- I have read that in my version of Raspbian, the necessary drivers for the STK1160 (v4l2) are pre-installed. I have verified this with `man v4l2-ctl`

My problem:

- When I try to load the driver with `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`, I get the following error: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted`. I am able to read in video with the camera, so it is not an issue with the camera's connection (however, the video feed is bad and looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHOFd74NCD0 must be a problem with the driver?)
- In addition, when I run `dmesg` I get the following error:

`bcm2835-v4l2: error -1 while loading driver`

I've spent about two weeks searching for an answer to this problem and the closest issue that I've found to my problem is on this link: [Camera, Ubuntu, modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 ERROR: could not insert 'bcm2835_v4l2': Operation not permitted](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32840/camera-ubuntu-modprobe-bcm2835-v4l2-error-could-not-insert-bcm2835-v4l2-op)

This user seems to have a very similar problem. However, I have a Raspberry Pi and I am not running Ubuntu. (I tried to ask this question on that thread but I don't have enough "reputation" yet).

Has anyone encountered this issue with a Raspberry Pi before?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be pretty amazed if the Pi could handle a live video feed via a USB dongle.  It is not very powerful.  Have you seen any reports of success?

Comment: Yea, I know someone who used the same model USB video capture card and a raspberry pi to capture live video. I am building off their project - only first I have to get it to work again! I should mention that I'm hoping to read in (and analyze) video at around 1fps.

Comment: bcm2835-v4l2 is the driver for **the official camera module** , not a generic V4L2 driver

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED:** with the command `lsmod`, you can see which drivers are installed. I had `v4l2_common` installed. I successfully loaded this driver with `sudo modprobe v4l2_common` (insert correct driver).

And yes, the pi can handle a live video feed!